# Word for songs used by rowers to synchronize their movements while rowing

Tags: single-word-requests, songs

While rowing, the rowers sing/chant songs which helps them coordinate their strokes and builds momentum. What are those songs called?

Comment: [*In the United States armed services, a **military cadence** or **cadence call** is a traditional **call-and-response work song** sung by military personnel while running or marching.*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Military_cadence) See [*There's more to cadences than just left-right-left*](https://www.army.mil/article/62043/theres_more_to_cadences_than_just_left_right_left#:~:text=Cadence%20is%20defined%20as%20the,marching%20or%20running%20in%20formation.) for more extensive use of the term with that domain-specific sense.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - This should be proposed as an answer.

Answer (score 21):

The French verb chanter (to sing) is the origin of the English **shanty**. Originally this word applied to rhythmical tasks aboard ship, such as rowing (or hauling large sails manually).

> [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sea_shanty)
> *shanty*
> A sea shanty, chantey, or chanty is a genre of traditional folk song that was once commonly sung as a work song to accompany rhythmical labor aboard large merchant sailing vessels. The term shanty most accurately refers to a specific style of work song belonging to this historical repertoire. However, in recent, popular usage, the scope of its definition is sometimes expanded to admit a wider range of repertoire and characteristics, or to refer to a "maritime work song" in general.
> ... Shanty songs functioned to synchronize and thereby optimize labor.

Even today there is interest in rowing shanties. Here is a contemporary advertisment:

> [Worksong Project](https://www.worksongs.org/products/rowing-shanties-on-eggemoggin-reach)
> Rowing Shanties on Eggemoggin Reach 6.3.19 $0.00
> Join us in a 10-oar Bantry Bay Gig as we revive old Sea Shanties from Maine and beyond. Grab an oar and bellow with the crew as we explore the area around the Deer Isle Bridge.

Comment: *Worksong* is in fact another potential answer.

Comment: Quite right, Anton. It's also worth noting the difference between shanties and other types of sea song such as forebitters. The general public tend to call all sea songs shanties including the lockdown meme The Wellerman which is a great sea song but not a shanty. I find it difficult to imagine any task that would be made easier by singing The Wellerman while doing it. Also shanties tend to be call-and-response songs as it's difficult to exert oneself while singing. A shantyman would typically sing but not, usually, exert himself much in the hard pulls.

Answer (score 3):

As per FumbleFinger's comment, especially if done as a call-and-response, this is sometimes known a [cadence call](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Military_cadence).

> Requiring no instruments to play, they are counterparts in oral military folklore of the military march. As a sort of work song, military cadences take their rhythms from the work being done (compare sea shanty). Many cadences have a call and response structure in which one soldier initiates a line, and the remaining soldiers complete it, thus instilling teamwork and camaraderie for completion. The cadence calls move to the beat and rhythm of the normal speed (quick time) march or running-in-formation (double time) march. This serves the purpose of keeping soldiers "dressed", moving in step as a unit and in formation, while maintaining the correct beat or cadence.

Comment: "I don't know, but I've been told" that cadence calls are usually associated with marching, not other activities.